# Netbalancer vs pfsense lan graph traffic? Which one is correct?

Tags: pfsense, bandwidth-measuring

I am researching on **wan** bandwith/speed checking tools/graphs. Normally we are using pfsence as a firewall/gateway/router. and also we were used to use "Traffic Graph" lan interface. 
Recently we have installed netbalancer https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/ .. 
But when we check/compare both at one time, there is a huge difference/anomaly..

[image]

Which one is ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are giving (roughly) the same data. Units matter. :)

pfSense is using mega**bits** per second, and Netbalancer is using mega**bytes** per second.